# SonarQube and .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, compact-framework, code-coverage

Does SonarQube support .NET Compact Framework 3.5 as well as the full framework versions?

Initially, the project would not build as the tools version wasn't specified. Once the tools versions was specified, the project was successfully built using msbuild v14. However, the SonarQube MS integration failed as SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about my project.

My build environment is set up with SonarQube v5.6.1, MSBuildTools v2015, SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild v2.1, and SonarQube C# Plugin v5.3.2.

I created the following batch script to run an analysis of a project so the begin, build, and end steps are launched from the same folder:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"myproject-6.0.8" /n:"myproject-6.0.8" /v:"6.0.8" /d:sonar.verbose=true
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /tv:3.5 /t:Rebuild "/p:Configuration=Debug,Platform=Any CPU" /verbosity:detailed "myproject.sln"
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

**From the outputlog**:

```
C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end   
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.1  
Default properties file was found at C:\myJunk\bin\sonarqube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml  
Loading analysis properties from C:\myJunk\bin\sonarqube\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml  
Post-processing started.  
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.1  
11:51:48.178  sonar.verbose=true was specified - setting the log verbosity to 'Debug'  
11:51:48.178  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml  
11:51:48.178  Not running under TeamBuild  
11:51:48.178  Analysis base directory: C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube  
Build directory:   
Bin directory: C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\bin  
Config directory: C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\conf  
Output directory: C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\out  
Config file: C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\out  
Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties  
The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.  
Possible causes:  
  1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps  
  2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported  
  3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder  
Writing processing summary to C:\Users\jgaoiran\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\myproject-6.0.8\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log  
Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.  
11:51:48.194  Creating a summary markdown file...  
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample project to help us reproducing this issue ? Thanks

Comment: In an environment with framework 4.5 is happening the same. What can be reviewed to solve it?